# Assembly code in C break instruction to get current time

Tags: c, assembly, inline-assembly

I need to write inline assembly code in C in format like this:

```
asm(
    "mov %1, %%ax\n\t"
    "inc %%ax\n"
    "mov %%ax, %0"
    :"=r" (a)
    :"r" (a)
    );
```

This code in asm() need to do break and assign current time to variables declared in C outside of asm() func. I have tried to write my own code but I even struggle to do break instruction... I'm on intel and using codeblock. Any good sources of inline-assembly are welcome too.
EDIT: I need something like this:

```
int 21h -> break
AH = 2Ah
CX -> year
DH -> month
DL -> day
AH = 2Ch
CH -> hour
CL -> min
DH -> sec
RET
```

Comment: So you're using GCC to compile for 16-bit DOS?  `int 21h` doesn't work anywhere else.  (Or some other compiler that supports GNU C extended asm).

Comment: This code is buggy: you forgot to tell the compiler that your asm clobbers `"ax"`.  Of course, you could have just done a `mov %1, %0` directly, and `inc %0`.  Both operands are registers.  Or better, only take one `"+r"` operand that you run `inc %0` on, and let the compiler use `mov` instructions if it wants the results in different registers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, when using gcc inline asm on x86, you NEVER want to include `mov` instructions, or explicit registers in the asm code.  Instead, you want to use the constraints to force inputs and output into specific registers.  The constraints available are:

```
+---+--------------------+
| r |    Register(s)     |
+---+--------------------+
| a |   %eax, %ax, %al   |
| b |   %ebx, %bx, %bl   |
| c |   %ecx, %cx, %cl   |
| d |   %edx, %dx, %dl   |
| S |   %esi, %si        |
| D |   %edi, %di        |
+---+--------------------+
```

This means that your increment example (putting a value into ax and incrementing) can be much more effectively written as:

```
asm("inc %0" : "+a" (a))
```

This forces the variable `a` into the ax register (assuming it is a 16-bit value) and increments it there.

One tricky problem is there are no constraints for `h` registers (upper 8 bits of 16 bit registers).  So if you want to do things with those, you need to use a 16 bit value and explicitly pack/unpack the pairs.  So for your int 21h/2Ah call, you would use something like:

```
uint16_t year, month_day;
asm("int 0x21" : "=c" (year), "=d" (month_day) : "a" (0x2a00));
uint8_t month = month_day >> 8;
uint8_t day = month_day;
```